# Cocos2D: Writing Text and getting input from a text field

Tags: xcode, text, cocos2d-iphone, field

Hi I'm having a hard time figuring how to just display simple text in a Cocos2D game.

I know how to write code to show pictures and to change the current picture but that's it. Can anyone help me with this?

Also I know making a text field requires UITextField but where exactly would I implement the code for that? I have classes the store how to start the game up and to create the pictures/display but that's it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily display text with CCLabel  Take a look at the documentation for it.  You'll see lots of warnings, though, that it's slow if you plan on update frequently (say, it's the players current score or a timer).  Then you'll want to look into CCLabelAtlas.

You can add UITextField, and other UIKit elements to your game by using a wrapper.  I'm partial to UIViewWrapper but there are probably other solutions. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889